# return JSON object for each row of data in excel

Tags: javascript, json, sheetjs

I'm working in webpack for SheetJS. I am relatively new to webpack and a total newbee with SheetJS. Instead of returning **one** JSON object of the Excel data, I want to return one JSON object for **each row** of data in the Excel.

Example input excel layout:

```
Col1     Col2      Col3
A2       B2        C2
A3       B3        C3
```

Ideal output in this example would be 2 JSON objects:
JSON 1:

```
{   
 "A2": [
        {
           "Col1": "A2"
           "Col2": "B2"
           "Col3": "C2"
        }
    ]
}
```

JSON 2:

```
 {   
    "A3": [
        {
           "Col1": "A3"
           "Col2": "B3"
           "Col3": "C3"
        }
    ]
 }
```

Attempted solution:

```
var to_json_linebyline = function to_json_linebyline(wb){
    var sheet = wb.Sheets['Sheet1'];
    var result = {};
    var row, rowNum, colNum;
    var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(sheet['!ref']);
    for(rowNum = range.s.r; rowNum <= range.e.r-2; rowNum++){
    row = [];
       for(colNum=range.s.c; colNum<=range.e.c; colNum++){
          var nextCell = sheet[
          XLSX.utils.encode_cell({r: rowNum, c: colNum})
       ];
       if( typeof nextCell === 'undefined' ){
          row.push(void 0);
       } else row.push(nextCell.w);
       }
       result[nextCell.v] = row;
    }
    return JSON.stringify(result, 2, 2);
}
```

Current result:

```
{
  "Col3": [
    "Col1",
    "Col2",
    "Col3"
  ],
  "C2": [
    "A2",
    "B2",
    "C2"
  ],
  "C3": [
    "A3",
    "B3",
    "C3"
  ]
}
```

Anything in the right direction'd be awesome. If it helps here's the [github repo](https://github.com/yi-ye-zhi-qiu/Excel-to-JSON-converter-line-by-line) .. thank you!

Comment: Can you share the contents of  `range` that you have used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're intent is right the code is wrong. You were defining and pushing data into arrays instead of creating a JSON object. Try this.

```
var to_json_linebyline = function to_json_linebyline(wb){
    var sheet = wb.Sheets['Sheet1'];
    var results = [];
    var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(sheet['!ref']);
    for(let rowNum = (range.s.r+1); rowNum <= range.e.r; rowNum++){
       let thisRow = {},
           thisNode = '';
       
       for(let colNum=range.s.c; colNum<=range.e.c; colNum++){
          var thisHeader = sheet[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({r: 0, c: colNum})].w
          var thisCell = sheet[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({r: rowNum, c: colNum})].w
          if(colNum === 0){ 
            thisNode = thisCell;
          }
          thisRow[thisHeader] = thisCell;
       }
       thisResult = {};
       thisResult[thisNode] = [thisRow]
       results.push(thisResult)
    }
    return JSON.stringify(results);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this works for me. I see.. results should be = [], not {}. I am finally starting to understanding how iteration is done in SheetJS, that range.s.r is cell index of first cell in range s of 0-index row and range.e.r is the last cell in range s. The header row is just cell address of row 0 and column of colNum, and cell itself is r: rowNum, not just r, so you get the "Col1": "A2" result, as opposed to just the cell value. Thank you!!

Comment: Correct. Once you get the iteration right, you can play with the output as you want it. If this helped, please upvote the answer as well so the question will be closed.

Comment: Right. I am trying to upvote but I think my reputation is too low :( kind of sad... but thank you!!